# Is it save to rewrite unsupported timezone UT to UTC?

Tags: java, timezone, email-validation

I try to parse Date-Headers in eMails.

Sometimes eMails have this Date-Header:

```
Mon, 18 Jul 2011 05:05:53 UT
```

Looks like the format described in the javadoc

[image]

So I wrote a test for this:

```
public void testParser() throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat FULL_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        String baddate = "Mon, 18 Jul 2011 05:05:53 UT";
        System.out.println("NOW: " + FULL_FORMAT.format(new Date()));
        System.out.println("THEN: " + FULL_FORMAT.parse(baddate + "C"));
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println(FULL_FORMAT.parse(baddate));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    System.out.println("UTC: " + TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println("UT: " + TimeZone.getTimeZone("UT"));
}
```

And this is the output:

```
[INFO] Running de.e_nexus.web.rm.mail.TestDateParser
NOW: Thu, 29 Feb 2024 11:50:52 +0100
THEN: Mon Jul 18 07:05:53 CEST 2011
---
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon, 18 Jul 2011 05:05:53 UT"
    at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:399)
    at de.e_nexus.web.rm.mail/de.e_nexus.web.rm.mail.TestDateParser.testParser(TestDateParser.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.PojoTestSetExecutor.executeTestMethod(PojoTestSetExecutor.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.PojoTestSetExecutor.execute(PojoTestSetExecutor.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:93)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
UTC: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
UT: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.044 s -- in de.e_nexus.web.rm.mail.TestDateParser
```

The Timezone UT clearly exists (might be similar or same like UTC) but Java does not support timezone UT afaict.

Is it save to rewrite UT to UTC?

Comment: A google search says that "UT" is a Utah time zone, which is UTC -7. So no, you will get the wrong time if you just rewrite UT to UTC.

Comment: @marstran I reat here https://academickids.com/encyclopedia/index.php/Coordinated_Universal_Time that UT is Zulu-Timezone. And `For most practical and legal-trade purposes, the fractional difference between UTC and UT (or, GMT) is inconsequentially small, and for this reason UTC is colloquially called GMT sometimes, even if this is not technically correct. `

Comment: by the way, I had one date `a.d. VII Kal. Iulias MMDCCLXX a.u.c.`, I will not seriously try to parse that :-D

Comment: And this page says it's Utah time: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/utah
So we cannot tell you which timezone you are getting.

Comment: @marstran I guess using UT as Utah-time-zone might have a national meaning. That might be the reason why JDK better not dare to make a fuss of this.

Comment: I gave it a try and parsed the date using `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US);` in order to verify a national understanding of Utah timezone, unfortunately it cant be parsed. If it could be parsed the UT confirmed to be Utah-time-zone. This try did neither prove Utah nor UTC.

Comment: "UT" isn't even listed [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/). Btw., Utah does not have its own tz, US/Mountain (MST/MDT) is used there. An appropriate IANA tz db time zone identifier would be "America/Denver". Another example why tz abbreviations are a programmers' pain.

Comment: @FObersteiner Yes it is listed there. Checkout the UTC entry. `Universal Time (UT) was created at the International Meridian Conference in 1884. This is the basis for the 24-hour time zone system we know today.` (ebenda)

Comment: uh yes, but that's UTC, not "UT" ^^ - not to be confused with UT1.

Comment: @FObersteiner indeed your right. It is not directly listed. But somehow indirectly listed it is.

Comment: Time zone abbreviations are scaringly often ambiguous. `UT` too.

Comment: Whatever you do. **do not use `SimpleDateFormat`**. That class had severe design problems and has been outdated for 10 years. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***What does "UT" stand for?***

Most likely "universal time". But don't nail me down on it, somebody might actually ship an app where this is "Utah time"* (please don't). Time zones are a political matter after all...

"Universal time" should be called Coordinated Universal Time / UTC. timeanddate.com has [a wrap-up of the basics](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html). "UT" is potentially unclear in its meaning (is it UTC but not coordinated? Is it UT1 and somebody forgot the 1?). However, it can be found for example in the IANA tz database repo docs ([example](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/NEWS#L2009)) or the RFC that describes the file format used to provide tz rules ([example](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8536#section-1)). Like UTC, it means solar time, not atomic time (TAI). There's a couple more related terms, see the [UTC Etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Etymology) section on the wikipedia. ***TL;DR***: use "UTC".

***Is it save to rewrite unsupported timezone UT to UTC?***

Datetime/Timezone libraries will accept "UTC" but less likely "UT". So you might want to replace it. ***TL;DR***: *Probably* that's safe. Can you be absolutely sure it's not Utah time? No.

---

*) Utah does not have its own tz, US/Mountain (MST/MDT) is used there. An appropriate IANA tz db time zone identifier would be "America/Denver".